# Pulling product description information with API?

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there a way to pull the product description area of a listing directly with the API? I'm able to get the title and bulletpoint information fine within the product API. But the product description area seems to be missing.

```
<Product>
  <Identifiers>
    <MarketplaceASIN>
      <MarketplaceId>Removed</MarketplaceId>
      <ASIN>B00BAWXD88</ASIN>
    </MarketplaceASIN>
  </Identifiers>
  <AttributeSets>
    <ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US">
      <ns2:Binding>Video Game</ns2:Binding>
      <ns2:Brand>Xseed</ns2:Brand>
      <ns2:Creator Role="Production Company">Xseed Jks Inc</ns2:Creator>
      <ns2:Edition>Standard</ns2:Edition>
      <ns2:ESRBAgeRating>Everyone 10+</ns2:ESRBAgeRating>
      <ns2:Feature>The popular spinoff from the 'Harvest Moon' series returns, combining farming and family life with monster battling and taming, with an all-new story that's accessible to new players and series veterans alike</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>Whether it be governing as the prince, tilling the fields, interacting with townsfolk, or heading to a dungeon to take on dangerous foes, the diverse amount of activities ensure that each day is a new adventure</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>Use swords, spears, staffs and other weapons and magic to personalize your battle tactics as formidable monsters await in trap-laden dungeons; invite the townsfolk along, develop friendships with certain monsters and grow stronger together</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>The main character can be male or female, and either gender can woo marriage candidates from among the townsfolk; communication and gift giving will be key to romance, potentially resulting in marriage and perhaps an adorable child together</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>The popular spinoff from the 'Harvest Moon' series returns, combining farming and family life with monster battling and taming, with an all-new story that's accessible to new players and series veterans alike</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>Whether it be governing as the prince, tilling the fields, interacting with townsfolk, or heading to a dungeon to take on dangerous foes, the diverse amount of activities ensure that each day is a new adventure</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>Use swords, spears, staffs and other weapons and magic to personalize your battle tactics as formidable monsters await in trap-laden dungeons; invite the townsfolk along, develop friendships with certain monsters and grow stronger together</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Feature>The main character can be male or female, and either gender can woo marriage candidates from among the townsfolk; communication and gift giving will be key to romance, potentially resulting in marriage and perhaps an adorable child together</ns2:Feature>
      <ns2:Genre>role-playing-game-genre</ns2:Genre>
      <ns2:HardwarePlatform>nintendo_3ds</ns2:HardwarePlatform>
      <ns2:ItemDimensions>
        <ns2:Height Units="inches">5.40</ns2:Height>
        <ns2:Length Units="inches">0.40</ns2:Length>
        <ns2:Width Units="inches">4.90</ns2:Width>
        <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.10</ns2:Weight>
      </ns2:ItemDimensions>
      <ns2:IsAdultProduct>false</ns2:IsAdultProduct>
      <ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>true</ns2:IsEligibleForTradeIn>
      <ns2:Label>Xseed</ns2:Label>
      <ns2:Languages>
        <ns2:Language>
          <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
          <ns2:Type>Published</ns2:Type>
        </ns2:Language>
        <ns2:Language>
          <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
          <ns2:Type>Original Language</ns2:Type>
        </ns2:Language>
        <ns2:Language>
          <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
          <ns2:Type>Unknown</ns2:Type>
        </ns2:Language>
      </ns2:Languages>
      <ns2:ListPrice>
        <ns2:Amount>29.99</ns2:Amount>
        <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
      </ns2:ListPrice>
      <ns2:Manufacturer>Xseed</ns2:Manufacturer>
      <ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge Units="months">12.00</ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge>
      <ns2:Model>81356</ns2:Model>
      <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
      <ns2:OperatingSystem>nintendo_3ds</ns2:OperatingSystem>
      <ns2:PackageDimensions>
        <ns2:Height Units="inches">0.70</ns2:Height>
        <ns2:Length Units="inches">5.40</ns2:Length>
        <ns2:Width Units="inches">4.90</ns2:Width>
        <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.15</ns2:Weight>
      </ns2:PackageDimensions>
      <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
      <ns2:PartNumber>81356</ns2:PartNumber>
      <ns2:PegiRating>ages_7_and_over</ns2:PegiRating>
      <ns2:Platform>Nintendo 3DS</ns2:Platform>
      <ns2:ProductGroup>Video Games</ns2:ProductGroup>
      <ns2:ProductTypeName>CONSOLE_VIDEO_GAMES</ns2:ProductTypeName>
      <ns2:PublicationDate>2013-10-02</ns2:PublicationDate>
      <ns2:Publisher>Xseed</ns2:Publisher>
      <ns2:ReleaseDate>2013-10-01</ns2:ReleaseDate>
      <ns2:SmallImage>
        <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/617jaCu3H5L._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
        <ns2:Height Units="pixels">65</ns2:Height>
        <ns2:Width Units="pixels">75</ns2:Width>
      </ns2:SmallImage>
      <ns2:Studio>Xseed</ns2:Studio>
      <ns2:Title>Rune Factory 4 - Nintendo 3DS</ns2:Title>
    </ns2:ItemAttributes>
  </AttributeSets>
  <Relationships/>
  <SalesRankings>
    <SalesRank>
      <ProductCategoryId>video_games_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
      <Rank>467</Rank>
    </SalesRank>
    <SalesRank>
      <ProductCategoryId>4924892011</ProductCategoryId>
      <Rank>22</Rank>
    </SalesRank>
  </SalesRankings>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is providing **_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_**, based on that we can get active product listing from amazon.

Report provide information like sku,title,description,ASIN..etc.. and It will give you information marketplace wise

You can get more info about report from below link.

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

This may help you.